# Concatenating HTML and PHP to make an image link

Tags: php, html, url, twitter

I'm trying to make an image into a link using PHP and HTML. The main idea is to grab user's images and screen names from Twitter, then make the image into a clickable link to their profile by building the URL and adding their screen name on the end. But I get a error message:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING, expecting ',' or ';' in C:\wamp\www\fyp\tweeter3.php on line 71.

This is line 71 (it's part of a foreach loop):

```
<?php echo "<a href = ".$url"><img src = ".$userImage." class = ".$class."></a>"; ?>
```

There's a syntax error in there I just can't pinpoint.
These are my variables:

```
$userScreenName = $user -> screen_name;
$userImage = $user -> profile_image_url;
$class = "myImgClass";
$url = "https://twitter.com/".$userScreenName;
```

Can you spot the error?

Comment: You are missing a period after `$url`.

Comment: You forgot a point and some quotes `<?php echo "<a href =\"".$url."\"><img src =\"".$userImage."\" class=\"".$class."\"></a>"; ?>`

Comment: I added the dot and it works now. Knew it would be something simple! Thanks everyone

Comment: You just need to add a dot after `$url`.

Comment: @Tiffany don't forget the HTML quotes :)

Comment: Seems to work without them!

Comment: ++1 Good catch! @Tiffany The HTML code won't work without them.

Comment: Adding in the quotes seems to do the same thing as just adding in the dot! Which bit won't work without the quotes?

Comment: @Tiffany the quotes are not for the php code. It is for the HTML code that will be generated. See my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing a dot after $url and the HTML quotes to generate valid code:

```
<?php echo "<a href = '".$url."'><img src = '".$userImage."' class = '".$class."'></a>"; ?>
```

Without the quotes you get:

```
<a href = the url><img src = user image class = the class></a>
```

With the quotes:

```
 <a href = 'the url'><img src = 'user image' class = 'the class'></a>
```

Answer (score 4):

Missing `.` after `$url`:

```
<?php echo "<a href = ".$url"><img...
```

Answer (score 2):

after $url you need to have a period.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
<?php 
echo "<a href = \"".$url."\"><img src = \"".$userImage."\" class = \"".$class."\"></a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the simplest and most readable way to do is:

```
<?php echo "<a href = '$url'><img src = '$userImage' class = '$class'></a>"; ?>
```

There is only one long text, and no concatenation is used. It reduces the possibility to have an error caused by a missing double quote or missing dot. All PHP variables will be replaced automatically by their values.

You could also use [printf](http://php.net/printf) to have all the variables outside of the string:

```
<?php printf('<a href = "%s"><img src = "%s" class = "%s"></a>', $url, $userImage, $class); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a good practise to concatenate html string with the php variables. This leads to possible injection vector (XSS). 
To avoid possible XSS (DOM OR STORED) please filter the variables as string. Specially if the value is from user input. 
eg.

```
<?php echo "<a href = '".filter_var($url, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING)."'
```