# php random images, links, text,

Tags: php

I am trying hard to figure out how to create a php code that displays images in a randomized fashion in this html, as well as href links, alt attributes and titles.

```
<ul>
   <li>
      <img src="http://www.prevention.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/102x104/images/news/featured_images/156854573-raw-meat-lab-628x363.jpg" alt="" title="" class="imagecache imagecache-102x104" height="104" width="102">    
      <p>    <a href="/food/healthy-eating-tips/theres-test-tube-burger-your-future">There?s A Test-Tube Burger In Your Future</a>
      </p>
   </li>
   <li>
      <img src="http://www.prevention.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/102x104/images/news/featured_images/86541117-grocery-shopping-produce-organic-label-mixed-greens-lg.jpg" alt="" title="" class="imagecache imagecache-102x104" height="104" width="102">    
      <p>    <a href="/food/smart-shopping/connecticut-gmo-labeling-law">GMOs?Exposed!</a>
      </p>
   </li>
</ul>
```

And here is my PHP code.

```
<?php
    $images = array('healthyfoods', 'mood7', '15_heart',
        'healthyf', 'visuals', 'healthyd', 'health01', 'crackers',
        'mmo', 'oo1', 'mushrooms', 'raw', 'vegetable', 'heal',
        '139572961', '3889');
    $i = rand(0, count($images)-1);
    $selectedImage = "../../images/main_body_image/{$images[$i]}.jpg";
?>
```

Comment: What did you try with PHP yet? **Show some `PHP code`...**

Comment: "*trying hard*" - Where? Show us what you've *tried* so we can help you and make you better instead of giving you the answer.

Comment: So what is the problem?  You've shown the code, but is it not doing what you want?  What happened when you tried it?  Did you get incorrect results?  Did you get *no* results?  If the results were incorrect, what made them incorrect?  What were you expecting instead?  Did you get *any* correct results?  If so, what were they?  Don't make us guess.

Comment: @user2665522 **+1 for the update**

Answer (score 2):

use PHP's `rand()` function to generate a random number, then just use that number to determine which image to show.

EDIT:

You cannot embed variables into PHP strings if it contains an array index, it just doesn't work, you'll need to concat the string manually, also the `{}` brackets will literally print directly into your string which you don't want, so take them out:

```
$selectedImage = "../../images/main_body_image/" . $images[$i] . ".jpg";
```

Once you have the image you want `$selectedImage`, you can create your HTML code where you want it via `echo`

```
// In the middle of your html code where you want to display your random image:
<?php echo '<img src="$selectedImage" height="104" width="102">'; ?>
```

`echo` makes the PHP literally print that text into your HTML, so it should be in HTML format.

Comment: ok, but, how to create href links and titles in <p></p> tags dynamically using perhaps php arrays (not using database), any idea, please?

Comment: PHP code gets mixed in with your html code, just use PHP code to conditionally include parts of your html and ignore other parts depending on your random number.

Comment: #this is the code I am using# <?php 
$images = array('healthyfoods', 'mood7', '15_heart', 'healthyf', 'visuals', 'healthyd', 'health01', 'crackers', 'mmo', 'oo1', 'mushrooms', 'raw', 'vegetable', 'heal', '139572961', '3889');
$i = rand(0, count($images)-1);
$selectedImage = "../../images/main_body_image/{$images[$i]}.jpg";
?>

Comment: I have updated my answer above

Comment: Thank you all including Lochemage. Your answers make it very clear to me.

Comment: @user2665522 *"ok, but, how to create href links..."* Add.. an `href`?. It will take 10 to 15 minutes *out of your life* to find the solution. There is... a "solution". (wink) And now to go have my T-bone steak on my trusty 'ol "silver platter"; yummy.

Comment: @user2665522 [**The Silver Platter**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15489467/1415724) - *"You're welcome"* - [**from results**](https://www.google.ca/search?q=how+to+add+an+href+to+my+images+php+concatenate&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=np&source=hp&gws_rd=cr)

Answer (score 1):

### There are quite a few possible solutions to your question.

I'll tell you what I would do:

1. #### Create an array containing the images data you like to display randomly

   *1b. If you've got **a lot of images** (100+), only put a limited amount in the array for better performance. Limit the returned amount in the function you use to fetch the image file paths ([Database Query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) or File-System with e.g. [`scandir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php), [`glob()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) or [`DirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.directoryiterator.php))*

   *1c. I recommend you to store the image data in a MySQL Database. It's faster and you can do more with it. See the example below.*
2. #### Then to randomize the order of the images you could use something like [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php)
3. #### Use [`foreach()`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) to loop through the array and [`echo`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) the images

### So, for example:

```
<?php
$images = array();  

// Get the images (just for this example, do it however you like).
// With sql queries ORDER BY RAND() could be used to randomize the results returned, but 
// it depends on the amount of data stored in the db. The more the slower the query will be.
$database->query('SELECT id, name, title, url, anchor_text, path FROM featured_images ORDER BY id LIMIT 10');

// Randomize the images
shuffle($images);

// Echo the randomized images
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    echo '<li>';
    echo '<img src="'.$image->path.'" alt="" title="'.$image->title.'" class="...>';
    echo '<p><a href="'.$image->url.'">'.$image->anchor_text.'</a></p>';
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

In the example code I used a basic SQL Query. To use SQL's native [RAND()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand), the following query could be used *(note that the LIMIT 10 is optional, but recommended to use when the table contains a lot of images, so adjust 10 to your needs) (also read the comment from the sql query in the example above about performance)*:

```
SELECT id, title, path FROM featured_images WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM featured_images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10)
```

I don't know how and were you get the image data from, but reading the data from a directory can be done like this *(note that a title and anchor text cannot be included with this approach, use the database variant from the above example instead, as it is also faster)*:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator("/path/to/images");
foreach ($dir as $file)
{
    $images[] = array(
        'path' => $file->getPath(), // file path w/o filename
        'name' => $file->getFilename(),
    );
}
```

Give this a try, fiddle around with it and read through PHP's Manual *(I linked the function names with the according manual pages)*.

Good luck.

---

## EDIT:

I'm updating this answer to provide `an array only solution` according to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18133589/php-random-images-links-text/18134525#comment26562196_18134525) from the questioner:

> Hi Markus, I am not using db since it's only a few images, can you give me hints about writing codes in foreach loop in case we use arrays? Thank you, Anay

Ok, so you want to use arrays with a small amount of images. I assume you're ["hard-coding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) the data into the script. Here we go:

```
<?php
// Since the image paths given in your example both conside in the same directory,
// you can create a base_path variable to prevent repeating the path over and over again
$imgBasePath = 'http://www.prevention.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/102x104/images/news/featured_images/';

// Create the array containing the required image data (hard-coded)
$images = array(
    array(
        'path'      => $imgBasePath . '156854573-raw-meat-lab-628x363.jpg',
        'title'     => '',
        'width'     => '102',
        'height'    => '104',

        'link_url'  => '/food/healthy-eating-tips/theres-test-tube-burger-your-future',
        'link_text' => 'There\'s A Test-Tube Burger In Your Future',
    ),

    array(
        'path'      => $imgBasePath . '86541117-grocery-shopping-produce-organic-label-mixed-greens-lg.jpg',
        'title'     => '',
        'width'     => '102',
        'height'    => '104',

        'link_url'  => '/food/smart-shopping/connecticut-gmo-labeling-law',
        'link_text' => 'GMOs-Exposed!',
    ),
);

// Now loop through the $images array and create the desired list
// I'm putting the html into a var to be more flexible of where to echo the created html
$html = '';
foreach ($images as $image)
{
    $html .= '<li>';

    $html .= '<img src="'.$image['path'].'" alt="" title="'.$image['title'].'" class="imagecache imagecache-102x104" width="'.$image['width'].'" height="'.$image['height'].'">';

    $html .= '<p><a href="'.$image['link_url'].'">'.$image['link_text'].'</a></p>';
    $html .= '</li>';
}

// Finally echo the list to the browser
echo '<ul>'.$html.'</ul>';
```

*[**Hard-coded**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_coding) means you're putting data into a script that is not dynamically changed. Fetching data from a database could be changed (e.g. updated or added), so it's dynamic. The way it's done in the example is called hard-coded).*

*[**The foreach loop**](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) walks through the $images array and returns each individual $image inside the loop. To access the $image data something like `$image['path']` is used. Pretty straight forward.*

This is a basic example of how to create arrays and use them in a foreach loop.

Happy coding.

Comment: Hi Markus, I am not using db since it's only a few images, can you give me hints about writing codes in foreach loop in case we use arrays? Thank you, Anay

Comment: @user2665522 Updated my answer. Have a look at the **EDIT:** part.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   define ('CRLF' , "\r\n");
   $images = array('healthyfoods|text desc1',
                          'mood7|text desc2',
                       '15_heart|text desc3',
                       'healthyf|text desc4',
                        'visuals|text desc5',
                       'healthyd|text desc6'); // you get the idea
   $i = mt_rand(0, count($images)-1);
   list ($filename, $alttext) = explode("|", $images[$i]);
   $selectedImage = "../../images/main_body_image/" . $filename . ".jpg";
   list($width, $height, $type, $attr) = getimagesize($selectedImage);
   $ho = '   <img src="' . $selectedImage . '" alt="' . $alttext . '" title="' . $alttext . '" ' . $attr . ' />' . CRLF;
 ?>
```

and in your HTML code:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <?php echo $ho; ?>
    <p> ...
```

Comment: Hi Dave, I think I should put the php code above the DOCTYPE.